# Reverse each word and not entire sentence MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I have a program that i need to reverse each word in a sentence.
I did my program, but it reverse each word and the sentence too, but i dont want to reverse the sentence.

Thats what i want in final:

```
My string: Razvan Balaci 
String print: navzaR icalaB
```

But my program prints:

```
 icalaB navzaR
```

Thats my code:

```
.data
string: .space 12
reverso: .space 12
menssagem: .asciiz "Enter in stringing, max 11 characters: "

.text
main:

la $a0, menssagem     #calling opening menssagem
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 8
la $a0, string
li $a1, 12
syscall

li $t1, 0

bump:
lbu $t0, string($t1)
beqz $t0, stend
addu $t1, $t1, 1
j bump

stend: 
li $t2, 0
addi $t1, $t1 -1

populate:
blt $t1, $zero, done
lb $t3, string($t1)
sb $t3, reverso($t2)
sub $t1, $t1, 1
add $t2, $t2, 1
j populate

done:
sb $zero, reverso($t2) #null terminate reverso
li $v0, 4
la $a0, reverso
syscall
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Maybe i need to do a sub-string?
Thank you.

Comment: Words are separated by a space. You can use use space and end of the string character (null character) to reverse. Read the string until you hit a space and reverse this part, leave the space as it is, and then do this for the rest of the string until you hit the last character.

Comment: @Azeem that was a nice tip, but i need help, where do i implement that?

Comment: design, implement, debug, the algorithm in your favorite language.  Then simply type out the assembly language that performs the same algorithm.  And no that doesnt mean use strok or anything like that, walk the string in C or Python or whatever.

Comment: @RazvanBalaci: You can follow the advice of _old_timer_ and do that. You can use Compiler Explorer (https://godbolt.org/) for code generation in MIPS. Here's an example for you: https://godbolt.org/g/QjVb7V.

Answer (score 0):

Some solution outline that may help:

-Reserve a small word-sized space (maybe 10-20 bytes).

-Reserve two spaces for the sentences (one for the original string and one for the result).

-Store 3 pointers to all three spaces.

-Loop with the pointer pointing at the original sentence (for each character) doing the following in each iteration:

- If the current character is not space or newline or null, put that character into the word-sized space and advance its pointer forward, then start the next iteration.
- Otherwise (i.e., if the character is ' ' or '\n' or '\0'), then start looping in reverse over the word we stored and put it into the "result"
  sentence (its pointer points now at the last character) until the pointer is back to the beginning of the space. Then add the ' ' or '\n' or '\0'
  you read into the result.

Hope it helps! You can do it even more efficiently than this if you want (the "result" space is not really needed for example).